# Siamese network in Keras symmetry issue

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm trying to implement a siamese network is Keras for textual similarity, but my network doesn't seem to be symmetrical. When I'm testing, the similarity score it is giving for A, B is different from B, A. How can I fix it? I have tried dot mode as well, as well as all Dense layers. My code is,

```
def contrastive(y_true, y_pred):
    margin = 1
    return K.mean(y_true * K.square(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0)))

def network():

    encoder = Sequential()
    encoder.add(Embedding(27, 15, input_length=15))
    encoder.add(LSTM(15))
    encoder.add(Dense(15))

    return encoder

l_twin = network()
r_twin = network()

merged = Merge([l_twin, r_twin], mode='cos', dot_axes=1)

siamese = Sequential()
siamese.add(merged)
siamese.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
siamese.compile(loss=contrastive, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = siamese.fit([l_encodings, r_encodings], target, epochs=5, batch_size=50)
siamese.save("siamese.h5")
siamese.save_weights("siamese_weights.h5")
```

Comment: The [official example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese.py) might be useful. You need to share weights across the two branches.

Comment: In which line of the official examples are they "sharing weights". I have tried to initialize the two networks with same dummy weights as well but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you are creating you are creating to different networks `network()`, so they will be independent.

As Yu-Yang said, check the [original example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese.py).

First, they create the layers only once
    # network definition
    base_network = create_base_network(input_shape)

Then they apply the network to two different inputs:

```
input_a = Input(shape=input_shape)
input_b = Input(shape=input_shape)

# because we re-use the same instance `base_network`,
# the weights of the network
# will be shared across the two branches
processed_a = base_network(input_a)
processed_b = base_network(input_b)
```

You should try using the functional API instead of the sequential to correct your code.